# What happens when Vdrain is greater than Vsource in PMOS Transistor?

Tags: transistors, pmos, linear, saturation

So as I understand, if Vsd = 0 in a pmos transistor, then the current flow should be zero, and the same goes for if Vs<Vd, now my question is, in what state will be the transistor i.e. cut-off, linear, or saturated if Vsg > Vth and Vsd = 0. Everywhere I looked the only condition for cut-off was Vsg > Vth, therefore is it possible for Isd = 0(Vsd<0) and the transistor still be in a linear  state if Vsd > Vsg-Vth?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing that determines the "on/off" state of the MOSFET (channel conductance) is the potential difference between gate and source, \$V_{GS}\$. As long as \$V_G\$ is significantly *less* than \$V_S\$ (for a P-channel device), meaning that \$V_G\$ is very negative with respect to \$V_S\$, the channel will conduct.

This has nothing to do with drain potential \$V_D\$. That's a slight over-simplification, in that drain potential does have *some* effect on channel conductivity, but in many cases it can be neglected.

What many people overlook, though, is the body diode in parallel with the channel, between drain and source. This diode becomes forward biased when drain potential \$V_D\$ is greater than the source \$V_S\$. So, when \$V_D > V_S\$, even though the channel may be in "cut-off" (\$V_{GS}=0\$), this diode will still conduct, and drain current will flow:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ni5F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In other words, for a normal 3-terminal P-channel MOSFET, if \$V_D > V_S\$, then the MOSFET will conduct from drain to source *regardless of gate potential*. In fact, the body diode will prevent \$V_{DS}\$ from exceeding 0.7V or so, just like any regular silicon diode would do.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the explanation, we weren't told about the body diode in parallel in class, but after your answer, I assume it is included in the transistor symbol. Thanks again, I believe I understand it now.

Comment: @NemoHolmes there are many symbols for MOSFETs depending on how last you want to be with drawing vs how many aspects of their behaviour you feel the need to emphasize (like whether to draw the body diode or not)

Answer (score 5):

I depends on how the body is connected. The MOSFET structure itself is symmetrical: for a P-channel device, the "source" is the connection to the channel that's at higher potential (which might not be the one labelled as "source").

In IC design, we usually connect the body to one of the supply rails (positive for P-channel, negative for N-channel). This allows us to exploit the symmetry to make bidirectional switches if that's what we need.

For a three terminal discrete MOSFET, the body is connected to the end of the channel that's identified as the "source". Then, you can't "reverse" bias the device by more than a diode drop. Even there, though, you may get a better reverse connection by biasing the gate enough to open the channel, operating the device "inverted" and avoiding the diode drop.